# Smooth out shaky jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I have an image that rotates and bounces around inside of a parent element. I have it working great, expect the rotation seems a bit hickupy. The first few seconds it's smooth then it starts shaking a bit.

How do I smooth this out?

```
$.fn.bounce = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        speed: 10
    }, options);

    return $(this).each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent(),
            height = $parent.height(),
            width = $parent.width(),
            top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height / 2)) + height / 4,
            left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width / 2)) + width / 4,
            vectorX = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1),
            vectorY = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);

        // place initialy in a random location
        $this.css({
            'top': top,
            'left': left
        }).data('vector', {
            'x': vectorX,
            'y': vectorY
        });

        var move = function($e) {

            var offset = $e.offset(),
                width = $e.width(),
                height = $e.height(),
                vector = $e.data('vector'),
                $parent = $e.parent();

            if (offset.left <= 0 && vector.x < 0) {
                vector.x = -1 * vector.x;
            }
            if ((offset.left + width) >= $parent.width()) {
                vector.x = -1 * vector.x;
            }
            if (offset.top <= 0 && vector.y < 0) {
                vector.y = -1 * vector.y;
            }
            if ((offset.top + height) >= $parent.height()) {
                vector.y = -1 * vector.y;
            }

            $e.css({
                'top': offset.top + vector.y + 'px',
                'left': offset.left + vector.x + 'px'
            }).data('vector', {
                'x': vector.x,
                'y': vector.y
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                move($e);
            }, 50);

        };

        move($this);
    });

};

$(function() {
    $('#wrapper li').bounce({
        'speed': 7
    });
});

$(function() {
    var $elie = $("img");
    rotate(0);
    function rotate(degree) {        
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            rotate(--degree);
        },30);
    }
});
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RalphLeMouf/k3uvb5c0/2/)**

Comment: #nsfw - that image is scary

Comment: For me, it's more jerky at the start, then settles down on its jerky-ness

Comment: The best way to fix your animations is to not use jQuery.

Comment: @ndugger what do you recommend that will be cross-browser and cross-device compatible?

Comment: I doubt you need to support legacy browsers all the way down to IE8, but GSAP is always recommended over jQuery animations (which are terrible and buggy) http://greensock.com/gsap

Comment: You could just make it go really fast http://jsfiddle.net/k3uvb5c0/3/ :)

Comment: Seriously though, the timeout length is why it's choppy, you may need a different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choppiness in your approach is from the timeout value of 50. A simple optimization is to just remove that interval and adjust the vector changes to keep the speed about the same.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  move($e);
}, 0);

vectorX = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0.1 : -0.1),
vectorY = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0.1 : -0.1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3uvb5c0/6/